# What are the practices when converting column data type in SQL Server Express 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I just recently hit the 10GB DB limit in SQL Server Express and am looking to drop unnecessary columns, and convert other columns to less heavy data types.  I have 29 columns, and just shy of 50M rows. Of that 29, 20 are floats, and only 10 of them are very useful to me. I could totally drop 10 of the float columns and still have all the information I need. Of the 6 remaining columns, 2 are bit, 2 are int (needed for a compound key), and 5 are int but could be tinyint.

How do I make sure that, before I change the data type of those 5 columns to tinyint, things will convert properly? SSMS warns be about potential data loss when doing it from Design, so I want to make sure things are fine before I go ahead and run the Alter Table statement.

Is it as simple as:

```
SELECT [ExperimentID],[CycleCount] --My compound key
FROM [dbo].[Simulations]
WHERE (parameter1 < 0 OR parameter1 > 255) OR (parameter2 < 0 OR parameter2 > 255) OR (other search conditions)
```

Or is there a better way to validate these things?

Also, sorry the DB isn't normalized properly, I was recommended not to normalize by a colleague in order to aid later data analysis.

Comment: Why floats? Do you need really high levels of not quite accurate precision in your numbers? For the tinyint conversion you could check MAX(ColumnName) to see if they will fit in a tinyint. I would likely disagree with your colleague about normalization. Table structure design should be made by how easy it is for the developer in the future. It should always be about properly storing the data but that is another topic entirely.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, this is only kicking the can down the road a ways.  If you're going to keep adding rows, you're going to to hit the 10GB limit again.  What are you going to do then?

Comment: This particular DB is storing results from some simulations. 56000/90000 have been run already, and I think that by dropping most of the floats and casting the ints as tinyints where I can, the DB will be well under 10GB. The floats are needed, as we need at least 6 digits of precision past the decimal point.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff, the plan if we do hit the 10GB limit is to make another identical DB with an empty simulations table, commit new data to there, and just do an inner join for data analysis.

Comment: I would suggest you to check this as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx - I hope you can keep your float values within 5 bytes instead of default 9.

Comment: The only thing that's slightly worrying is that the application has double precision floats, which get committed to the DB as the float datatype. This works, and I'm not sure if I want to change this and risk data corruption. Silly, but important.

Comment: Well, with the solution in my answer you can always check what happens to your data if you change its type.

Comment: I'm making a backup to play around with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you want to change type of the column you can CAST-Select it to make sure everything goes ok:

```
SELECT CAST(Column_Name as tinyint), *
FROM [dbo].[Simulations]
```

If there are int values it will raise exception.

If you try to shorten strings (like changing varchar(1000) to varchar(100)) there will be message that data will be truncated.

Comment: I would also suggest you to check file sizes, as most part of your DB might be log file, which I suppose is useless for you. Read more here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189272.aspx - You need to change recovery model to simple and then shrink log file to 0.

Comment: The log for the entire DB is on 20MB, so I don't think it's the problem. I like to have it for the "just in case"

Comment: Then yeah, 20MB doesn't make sense so better keep it, although after you batch update all your data to change the types of the columns it might grow huge at once.

Comment: It's limited to 200MB, but I'll keep an eye on it after altering the table.

Comment: Why does DBCC Cleantable not free space? I can't do a REBUILD because it says I dont

Comment: DBCC CLEANTABLE reclaims space after a variable-length column is dropped. A variable-length column can be one of the following data types: varchar, nvarchar, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary, varbinary(max), text, ntext, image, sql_variant, and xml. The command does not reclaim space after a fixed-length column is dropped. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx